# Angular 4 change css by id

Tags: css, angular, styles

I am trying to change CSS property by element ID using vanilla JS?

I am trying to achieve the following effect:

1. After the first button is clicked on the bottom bottom, the first button on the top should change it's class from `btn-dark` to `btn-warning`.
2. The remaining buttons should follow this same pattern: #b2 clicked should result in #d2 being changed from `btn-dark` to `btn-warning`.

**My current attempt**:

```
<div class="row">
    <button *ngFor="let number of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]" 
    type="button" 
    class="btn btn-dark"
    id="d{{number}}" 
    >
    </button>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <button (click)="onClick($event)" 
    *ngFor="let number of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]" 
    type="button" 
    class="btn btn-secondary" 
    id="b{{number}}">{{number}}
    </button>
</div>
```

[Screenshot displaying the template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaQj7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass), e.g.:

```html
<button [ngClass]="{'btn-dark': true}">...</button>
```

Comment: Yes, but works for all #d elements. I want to change one of them

Comment: Add ngClass for each buttons separately

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

it will changed one of them at a time

[stackblitz demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iadjfv?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thanks, very much! I didn't know that it's so simple. These are my first steps with Angular.